# Latex install packages in home

Tags: linux

I am using latex on a Linux system without root-access but I am missing several
style files for compilation.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `currvita.sty' not found.
```

I know that I could copy the missing files directly in the folder with the .tex file but that helps only with the current document.

Is there a way to install the latex packages in my home so I have them available for all documents and avoid using the distribution package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should set `TEXINPUTS` variable: it stores the directories where your files place:

```
TEXINPUTS=.:/your/desired/path
```

(Note the first `.` - this will the current working directory)

Copy your files to `/your/desired/path` and run `mktexlsr /your/desired/path`.

See [man tex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tex) for more.